# Set multiple conrtols to one storyboard

Tags: wpf, animation, storyboard

I have multiple (dynamically created) controls in a grid (labels, buttons), and one storyboard!
I can assign a storyboard to one control, but I want to apply the storyboard's animation in each controls...how can I do this?

My code:

```
Storyboard myStoryboard1 = new Storyboard();
Label label1 = new Label();
Label label2 = new Label();
Label label3 = new Label();
...
Storyboard.SetTarget(myAnimation2, Label1);
Storyboard.SetTarget(myAnimation2, Label2);
Storyboard.SetTarget(myAnimation2, Label3);
```

This code is set the animation only to the Label3...

Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, I missed it...
myAnimation2 is a DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames, and I add the animation to the storyboard...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to do this is by making one or multiple styles for all the control types that you want to animate and [base them all on a single style](http://timsbrownbaglunch.blogspot.nl/2009/09/wpf-styles-and-animations.html) that contains the storyboard/animation.

Then, after you create/add a control just set its style (or make the styles the default styles)

```
var newLabel = new Label();
newLabel.Style = this.TryFindResource("controlStyle") as Style;
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply!

Ok I understand, I need a style... but how can I create a style from code(not XAML) which is contain my animation? I can't found any example for this...

Comment: So, I have the storyboard and a style. I add the style to the controls. But how can I link the storyboard to the style?

Comment: When do you want the storyboard to be played?

Comment: Ah, sorry in that case the style won't help. You'll need to keep the storyboard separate (you could put it in the window or app resources). See this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1654355/define-animations-and-triggers-as-reusable-resource to see how to reuse an animation/storyboard

Comment: Thx, I saw the linked topic and try to apply it... 
I didn't think that link an animation to the controls is so complicated...